# Can not follow stack trace

Tags: html, debugging, nuxt.js, stack-trace, vue-storefront

I am debugging my Vue Storefront project, which is based on Nuxt.js

The error I currently face is: `TypeError: Invalid URL` which is not too informative.

The Stack trace shows `getIntergrationConfig` in the `src/utils/nuxt`folder. I can not seem to find either the folder or the function that is called in my project.

How can I still trace back the origin of the error I am facing?

[image]

Comment: Do you have your env variables set?

Comment: @kissu I do have a .ENV file that's is correctly set. I can't however seem to find what URL is missing or which one is wrong :/

Comment: Hard to help with just a screenshot tbh. Try your luck on the Github issues or please provide a repro.

Comment: @kissu this is the repo I use: https://github.com/vuestorefront/vue-storefront . It's not that I don't want to debug it myself, but I am new to debugging like this

Comment: What did you tried with that repo? You're pointing the one of the project here, not your own. Or do you have an issue with a basic setup even?

Comment: @kissu wel yes, I am still at set-up indeed. That why I was happy that I linked the Env file but got this, so vague, error message. How can I debug this error using the repo?

Comment: E-commerce is a big topic. And here, it's probably not a debug topic but more of a setup one. You should probably read the documentation as how to setup your Woocomerce or alike, since the 2 are probably heavily tied. Otherwise, you could also ask this specific question on the [Discord of Nuxt](https://discord.gg/QfCSZPWc) or directly to some people working there. Like [Jakub](https://twitter.com/jacobandrewsky). He will be quite more efficient than me at helping you on this subject.

Comment: @kissu Thanks, I will reach out to these sources! Dutchies unite ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244512/discussion-between-craws-and-kissu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by looking into your error, it seems that is related to how our Core is handling the URL mounting process.

The `getIntegrationConfig` it's a function on the VSF Core (https://github.com/vuestorefront/vue-storefront/blob/12feb05f644fd21998cd3c69a3f3e576e3359bba/packages/core/core/src/utils/nuxt/_proxyUtils.ts)

It will define the API URL that the Nuxt will use to communicate between the front and VSF API

```js
export const getIntegrationConfig = (context: NuxtContext, configuration: any) => {
  const baseURL = process.server ? context?.$config?.middlewareUrl : window.location.origin;
  const cookie = getCookies(context);

  if (process.server && context?.$config?.middlewareUrl) {
    Logger.info('Applied middlewareUrl as ', context.$config.middlewareUrl);
  }

  return merge({
    axios: {
      baseURL: new URL(/\/api\//gi.test(baseURL) ? '' : 'api', baseURL).toString(),
      headers: {
        ...(cookie ? { cookie } : {})
      }
    }
  }, configuration);
};
```

As your error continues, we see that it will be triggered in the `new URL` class creation, when passing the constructor to the URL class.

If we look at the code we can take as assumptions that the `baseURL` is not being defined properly.

What I can suggest is for you to define in your `nuxt.config.js` file the server middleware URL (https://docs.vuestorefront.io/v2/security/api-url.html)